# AS3 mobile app multiple background colours

Tags: actionscript-3

I have setup a new mobile app using AS3/AIR which will be for iOS and Android but I want to have multiple background colours.

I am using Feathers UI to manage screen transitions and would like 2 screens to be black and the rest to be white. I know I could use a background image and tile but thought I would check if it were possible to simply change the colour.

Cheers

Comment: Why not place a different colored Quad in each screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using flat colours you can simply create Quads:

```
private var _bg1:starling.display.Quad;

_bg1 = new Quad(_stageWidthValue, _stageHeightValue, 0xFF0000);
_bg1.touchable = false;
addChildAt(_bg1, 0);
```